# Ссылка на переменные посредством цикла

Tags: python, ссылки

Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно реализовать следующее:
Имеется 20 переменных

```
a1=Андрей 
a2=Алексей 
a3=Максим 
a4=Дмитрий
```

и т.д.
Как можно вызвать их все не прописывая каждую в отдельности?
Например функцией принт.
Я пытался циклом вот так:

```
for i in range (1, 21):
    print(a+i)
```

Но возникает ошибка, что я делаю не так, может есть другой способ вызова всех переменных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно вызвать переменную по её названию в виде строки, а название сделать нетрудно:

```py
a1 = 123
a2 = True
a3 = '°^π°='

for i in range(1,4):
  print(globals()['a'+str(i)])
```

Но это довольно плохое решение. Если вам нужно хранить данные подобным образом, лучше воспользоваться списками:

```py
a = [123, True, '°^π°']
for elem in a:
  print(elem)
```